# websockets library for .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I need to work with websockets in **.net 3.5.**, however, most implementations require .net 4 or 4.5 ...

Does anyone know of or have recommendations for a good opensource C# websockets implementation that is actively maintained and is compatible with .net 3.5?

Comment: Hi, we have been using WebSocket4Net and it works very well